# ArchLinux - system hangs and becomes unresponsive

Tags: linux, memory, hardware-failure, hung

I have been having issues with a particular laptop for several weeks.  Another one with the same OS and updates is running fine (so I am thinking this is a hardware issue).  The system appears to hang when I do a lot of IO activity (like copying a file, or any CPU intensive task).  It does not appear to come back to life unless I restart the computer.  I originally thought it was an issue with firefox or chromium, and then flashplayer.  Once I killed firefox or chromium, my computer would become responsive again, but would eventually become unresponsive again.

I see this in dmesg:

```
[ 4921.149605] firefox         D 000000010014761b     0  2708   2172 0x00000000
[ 4921.149613]  ffff8800d823fd50 0000000000000086 ffff880100000000 ffff8800d344e
d80
[ 4921.149621]  ffff880037f864a0 ffff8800d823ffd8 ffff8800d823ffd8 ffff8800d823f
fd8
[ 4921.149629]  ffff8801192a4f10 ffff880037f864a0 ffff8800d3508900 ffff8800d0c14
d80
[ 4921.149636] Call Trace:
[ 4921.149648]  [<ffffffff8116a5b0>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
[ 4921.149655]  [<ffffffff810622e6>] ? current_fs_time+0x16/0x60
[ 4921.149662]  [<ffffffff813f2c4f>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x23f/0x330
[ 4921.149668]  [<ffffffff81170b3f>] ? touch_atime+0x13f/0x180
[ 4921.149674]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 4921.149679]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 4921.149685]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 4921.149693]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 4921.149698]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 4921.149704]  [<ffffffff810398c1>] do_page_fault+0x191/0x4d0
[ 4921.149710]  [<ffffffff813f46c5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
[ 4921.149719] INFO: task firefox:27933 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 4921.149727] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 4921.149729] firefox         D 00000001001474f5     0 27933   2172 0x00000000
[ 4921.149733]  ffff8800d0f77e18 0000000000000086 ffff880000000000 ffff8800d0c85
6c0
[ 4921.149738]  ffff8801177a40b0 ffff8800d0f77fd8 ffff8800d0f77fd8 ffff8800d0f77
fd8
[ 4921.149742]  ffff8801192a4f10 ffff8801177a40b0 ffff8800d0f77da8 ffffffff81165
ab8
[ 4921.149747] Call Trace:
[ 4921.149750]  [<ffffffff81165ab8>] ? do_last+0xb8/0x960
[ 4921.149753]  [<ffffffff811671df>] ? path_openat+0xff/0x3c0
[ 4921.149756]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 4921.149759]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 4921.149763]  [<ffffffff813f3a73>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
[ 4921.149766]  [<ffffffff812264e3>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
[ 4921.149769]  [<ffffffff813f30c5>] ? down_write+0x25/0x27
[ 4921.149773]  [<ffffffff81124802>] sys_mmap_pgoff+0x122/0x230
[ 4921.149777]  [<ffffffff81010262>] sys_mmap+0x22/0x30
[ 4921.149780]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 4921.149788] INFO: task pidof:12730 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 4921.149790] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 4921.149792] pidof           D 000000010014756c     0 12730  12729 0x00000000
[ 4921.149796]  ffff88009b465c90 0000000000000086 ffffffff00000000 00007f61f01ee
000
[ 4921.149801]  ffff8800d0ca0730 ffff88009b465fd8 ffff88009b465fd8 ffff88009b465
fd8
[ 4921.149805]  ffffffff8169b020 ffff8800d0ca0730 0000000000000014 0000000000000
000
[ 4921.149810] Call Trace:
[ 4921.149814]  [<ffffffff81115b99>] ? zone_statistics+0x99/0xc0
[ 4921.149817]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 4921.149820]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 4921.149824]  [<ffffffff81088464>] ? in_group_p+0x34/0x40
[ 4921.149827]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 4921.149831]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 4921.149834]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 4921.149837]  [<ffffffff8111ffae>] __access_remote_vm+0x3e/0x1d0
[ 4921.149841]  [<ffffffff811240c3>] ? mmap_region+0x233/0x4d0
[ 4921.149843]  [<ffffffff8112040b>] access_process_vm+0x5b/0x80
[ 4921.149847]  [<ffffffff811b3703>] proc_pid_cmdline+0x93/0x120
[ 4921.149852]  [<ffffffff81138313>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xa3/0x110
[ 4921.149855]  [<ffffffff811b400d>] proc_info_read+0xad/0x100
[ 4921.149859]  [<ffffffff81157c6c>] vfs_read+0xac/0x180
[ 4921.149861]  [<ffffffff81157d8a>] sys_read+0x4a/0x90
[ 4921.149865]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 5041.149562] INFO: task firefox:2708 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5041.149567] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5041.149570] firefox         D 000000010014761b     0  2708   2172 0x00000000
[ 5041.149575]  ffff8800d823fd50 0000000000000086 ffff880100000000 ffff8800d344e
d80
[ 5041.149581]  ffff880037f864a0 ffff8800d823ffd8 ffff8800d823ffd8 ffff8800d823f
fd8
[ 5041.149585]  ffff8801192a4f10 ffff880037f864a0 ffff8800d3508900 ffff8800d0c14
d80
[ 5041.149589] Call Trace:
[ 5041.149599]  [<ffffffff8116a5b0>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
[ 5041.149603]  [<ffffffff810622e6>] ? current_fs_time+0x16/0x60
[ 5041.149608]  [<ffffffff813f2c4f>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x23f/0x330
[ 5041.149612]  [<ffffffff81170b3f>] ? touch_atime+0x13f/0x180
[ 5041.149616]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5041.149619]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5041.149622]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 5041.149627]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 5041.149630]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 5041.149634]  [<ffffffff810398c1>] do_page_fault+0x191/0x4d0
[ 5041.149638]  [<ffffffff813f46c5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
[ 5041.149641] INFO: task firefox:2821 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5041.149643] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5041.149645] firefox         D 000000010014fc65     0  2821   2172 0x00000000
[ 5041.149650]  ffff8800d0c13dd0 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 ffff8800d0c13
d08
[ 5041.149654]  ffff88010e148e60 ffff8800d0c13fd8 ffff8800d0c13fd8 ffff8800d0c13
fd8
[ 5041.149658]  ffffffff8169b020 ffff88010e148e60 0000000000000020 ffff88010f3ab
910
[ 5041.149663] Call Trace:
[ 5041.149667]  [<ffffffff8138196d>] ? tcp_transmit_skb+0x3dd/0x8c0
[ 5041.149671]  [<ffffffff81140328>] ? add_partial+0x58/0x90
[ 5041.149675]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5041.149678]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5041.149681]  [<ffffffff81141afb>] ? kmem_cache_free+0x14b/0x160
[ 5041.149684]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 5041.149688]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 5041.149691]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 5041.149694]  [<ffffffff81119b3d>] sys_madvise+0x7d/0x740
[ 5041.149697]  [<ffffffff8115958f>] ? fput+0x16f/0x210
[ 5041.149701]  [<ffffffff81155d96>] ? filp_close+0x66/0x90
[ 5041.149704]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 5041.149709] INFO: task firefox:27933 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5041.149711] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5041.149713] firefox         D 00000001001474f5     0 27933   2172 0x00000000
[ 5041.149717]  ffff8800d0f77e18 0000000000000086 ffff880000000000 ffff8800d0c85
6c0
[ 5041.149722]  ffff8801177a40b0 ffff8800d0f77fd8 ffff8800d0f77fd8 ffff8800d0f77
fd8
[ 5041.149726]  ffff8801192a4f10 ffff8801177a40b0 ffff8800d0f77da8 ffffffff81165
ab8
[ 5041.149730] Call Trace:
[ 5041.149734]  [<ffffffff81165ab8>] ? do_last+0xb8/0x960
[ 5041.149737]  [<ffffffff811671df>] ? path_openat+0xff/0x3c0
[ 5041.149740]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5041.149743]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5041.149746]  [<ffffffff813f3a73>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
[ 5041.149750]  [<ffffffff812264e3>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
[ 5041.149753]  [<ffffffff813f30c5>] ? down_write+0x25/0x27
[ 5041.149756]  [<ffffffff81124802>] sys_mmap_pgoff+0x122/0x230
[ 5041.149761]  [<ffffffff81010262>] sys_mmap+0x22/0x30
[ 5041.149764]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 5041.149772] INFO: task pidof:12730 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5041.149774] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5041.149776] pidof           D 000000010014756c     0 12730  12729 0x00000000
[ 5041.149780]  ffff88009b465c90 0000000000000086 ffffffff00000000 00007f61f01ee
000
[ 5041.149784]  ffff8800d0ca0730 ffff88009b465fd8 ffff88009b465fd8 ffff88009b465
fd8
[ 5041.149789]  ffffffff8169b020 ffff8800d0ca0730 0000000000000014 0000000000000
000
[ 5041.149793] Call Trace:
[ 5041.149797]  [<ffffffff81115b99>] ? zone_statistics+0x99/0xc0
[ 5041.149800]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5041.149803]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5041.149807]  [<ffffffff81088464>] ? in_group_p+0x34/0x40
[ 5041.149811]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 5041.149814]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 5041.149817]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 5041.149820]  [<ffffffff8111ffae>] __access_remote_vm+0x3e/0x1d0
[ 5041.149824]  [<ffffffff811240c3>] ? mmap_region+0x233/0x4d0
[ 5041.149827]  [<ffffffff8112040b>] access_process_vm+0x5b/0x80
[ 5041.149830]  [<ffffffff811b3703>] proc_pid_cmdline+0x93/0x120
[ 5041.149834]  [<ffffffff81138313>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xa3/0x110
[ 5041.149837]  [<ffffffff811b400d>] proc_info_read+0xad/0x100
[ 5041.149841]  [<ffffffff81157c6c>] vfs_read+0xac/0x180
[ 5041.149843]  [<ffffffff81157d8a>] sys_read+0x4a/0x90
[ 5041.149847]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 5161.149582] INFO: task firefox:2708 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5161.149588] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5161.149593] firefox         D 000000010014761b     0  2708   2172 0x00000000
[ 5161.149601]  ffff8800d823fd50 0000000000000086 ffff880100000000 ffff8800d344e
d80
[ 5161.149609]  ffff880037f864a0 ffff8800d823ffd8 ffff8800d823ffd8 ffff8800d823f
fd8
[ 5161.149616]  ffff8801192a4f10 ffff880037f864a0 ffff8800d3508900 ffff8800d0c14
d80
[ 5161.149624] Call Trace:
[ 5161.149636]  [<ffffffff8116a5b0>] ? __pollwait+0xf0/0xf0
[ 5161.149643]  [<ffffffff810622e6>] ? current_fs_time+0x16/0x60
[ 5161.149650]  [<ffffffff813f2c4f>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x23f/0x330
[ 5161.149657]  [<ffffffff81170b3f>] ? touch_atime+0x13f/0x180
[ 5161.149663]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5161.149668]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5161.149674]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 5161.149681]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 5161.149686]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 5161.149692]  [<ffffffff810398c1>] do_page_fault+0x191/0x4d0
[ 5161.149703]  [<ffffffff813f46c5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
[ 5161.149707] INFO: task firefox:2821 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5161.149709] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5161.149711] firefox         D 000000010014fc65     0  2821   2172 0x00000000
[ 5161.149715]  ffff8800d0c13dd0 0000000000000086 0000000000000000 ffff8800d0c13
d08
[ 5161.149720]  ffff88010e148e60 ffff8800d0c13fd8 ffff8800d0c13fd8 ffff8800d0c13
fd8
[ 5161.149724]  ffffffff8169b020 ffff88010e148e60 0000000000000020 ffff88010f3ab
910
[ 5161.149728] Call Trace:
[ 5161.149733]  [<ffffffff8138196d>] ? tcp_transmit_skb+0x3dd/0x8c0
[ 5161.149737]  [<ffffffff81140328>] ? add_partial+0x58/0x90
[ 5161.149740]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5161.149743]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5161.149746]  [<ffffffff81141afb>] ? kmem_cache_free+0x14b/0x160
[ 5161.149749]  [<ffffffff813f3a95>] rwsem_down_read_failed+0x15/0x17
[ 5161.149753]  [<ffffffff812264b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[ 5161.149756]  [<ffffffff813f3097>] ? down_read+0x17/0x20
[ 5161.149759]  [<ffffffff81119b3d>] sys_madvise+0x7d/0x740
[ 5161.149763]  [<ffffffff8115958f>] ? fput+0x16f/0x210
[ 5161.149766]  [<ffffffff81155d96>] ? filp_close+0x66/0x90
[ 5161.149770]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 5161.149775] INFO: task firefox:27933 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 5161.149777] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this
message.
[ 5161.149779] firefox         D 00000001001474f5     0 27933   2172 0x00000000
[ 5161.149783]  ffff8800d0f77e18 0000000000000086 ffff880000000000 ffff8800d0c85
6c0
[ 5161.149788]  ffff8801177a40b0 ffff8800d0f77fd8 ffff8800d0f77fd8 ffff8800d0f77
fd8
[ 5161.149792]  ffff8801192a4f10 ffff8801177a40b0 ffff8800d0f77da8 ffffffff81165
ab8
[ 5161.149796] Call Trace:
[ 5161.149799]  [<ffffffff81165ab8>] ? do_last+0xb8/0x960
[ 5161.149803]  [<ffffffff811671df>] ? path_openat+0xff/0x3c0
[ 5161.149806]  [<ffffffff8105641f>] schedule+0x3f/0x60
[ 5161.149809]  [<ffffffff813f39c5>] rwsem_down_failed_common+0xc5/0x160
[ 5161.149812]  [<ffffffff813f3a73>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
[ 5161.149816]  [<ffffffff812264e3>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x13/0x20
[ 5161.149819]  [<ffffffff813f30c5>] ? down_write+0x25/0x27
[ 5161.149822]  [<ffffffff81124802>] sys_mmap_pgoff+0x122/0x230
[ 5161.149826]  [<ffffffff81010262>] sys_mmap+0x22/0x30
[ 5161.149829]  [<ffffffff813f4c82>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 5750.501897] chromium-sandbo (12920): /proc/12918/oom_adj is deprecated, pleas
e use /proc/12918/oom_score_adj instead.
```

It looks like maybe I have some bad memory - also my hard drive is indicating it is in prefail state.  I don't know if that would contribute or not (I doubt it since all of these programs should be in memory already).

I ran a memory test, memtest86, and it found no errors.  Is my memory bad, or what else is going on here?  I want to know what is broken in my system and if you have any ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Your question is missing. Are you asking if this is a memory or a harddrive failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may be a bug with gnome-session / gnome-shell as I have seen reports of this happening in Fedora recently on both nvidia and ati systems.  It is peculiar though that this issue just started happening right around the time of the 3.2 upgrade and it doesn't occur on my other system running this OS and version as well.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  I just reproduced this issue with SLiM and XFCE4.

Comment: Maybe something else worth noting is that I occasionally cannot boot up to the USB 2.0 hard drive, I get volume group not found.  I am thinking this is more a hard drive failure than memory or GPU, etc.

Comment: Actually, I ran a full day without any errors, it appeared to be because I wasn't running dual monitors.  I'm not sure why I get this error on this machine and not another one if the issue is purely software.

Comment: After the latest upgrades I am getting the same kind of error on Archlinux - "Task xxxx blocked for more than 120 seconds" with a number of apps. Using xfce4.10 with lxdm.